# Proof of well-founded order relation on the set of all finite directed binary trees.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, trees

Consider the set of all finite directed binary trees with vertices $V$ and edges $E$. If $T_i=(V_i, E_i)$, $i=1,2$ are trees in this set, then we say $T_1 \sqsubseteq T_2$ if and only if $V_1 \subseteq V_2$ and $E_1$ is the set of all edges in $E_2$ with tail in $V_1$.

As a small exercise in the lecture notes, the reader is asked to prove that $\sqsubseteq$ is a well-founded order. Well-foundedness would follow directly from the fact that the single vertex is a minimal element of any FINITE directed tree. Is there more I should say about any tails connected to it?

Secondly, I wish to prove it is an order relation. We need not think hard about the vertices since $V_1 \subseteq V_2$ is a well-defined order relation called set inclusion and this has all the properties of reflexivity, antisymmetry and transitivity. Now the hard part would be to prove that the second statement "$E_1$ is the set of all edges in $E_2$ with tail in $V_1$" also satisfies the transitive, antisymmetric and reflexive definitions. I would say that for any tree, all of its edges are contained in itself and its tail is in itself, so reflexivity is trivial.

But what about the other two properties? This section is building up to induction so I am not sure if we need to use that yet or if it is required. But it feels like overkill.

Comment: "Well-foundedness would follow directly from the fact that the single vertex is a minimal element of any FINITE directed tree." This doesn't give that $\sqsubseteq$ is well-founded. You need to show that every collection of finite directed binary trees has a minimal element.

Comment: "But what about the other two properties?" You don't need induction here. You have $(V_1, E_1) \sqsubseteq (V_2, E_2) \sqsubseteq (V_3, E_3)$. Now carefully go through the requirements of $\sqsubseteq$ to show that this implies $(V_1,E_1) \sqsubseteq (V_3,E_3)$. Regarding totality: If I understand the relation (and its domain) correctly, $\sqsubseteq$ is not a total order. Since, for example $(\{1\}, \emptyset), (\{2\}, \emptyset)$ are $\sqsubseteq$-incompatible.

Comment: But I didn't want to prove totality...

Comment: What's your definition of a order relation then?

Comment: Reflexive, anti-symmetric and transitive. Furthermore if we can compare any two elements this order will be called linearly ordered or equivalentally, totally ordered.

Comment: Okay, in that sense $\subseteq$ is an order (which some authors would call a partial order to better distinguish it from total orders). Antisymmetry goes something like this. Let $(V_1,E_1) \sqsubseteq (V_2,E_2) \sqsubseteq (V_1,E_1)$. Then $V_1 \subseteq V_2 \subseteq V_1$ (which implies $V_1 = V_2$). It remains to show that $E_1 = E_2$. But if $e = (u,v) \in E_1$, then $u,v \in V_1 = V_2$. But this implies $(u,v) \in E_2$ because ... likewise we get $E_2 \subseteq E_1$ and hence $(V_1,E_1) = (V_2,E_2)$.

Comment: Since the amount of vertices/edges is a natural number, and those are well-ordered so must contain a smallest element, can I say that binary trees must contain smallest element(s)? Some sort of counting argument.... I really have no idea if I'm moving in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah we call partial orders, orders.

Comment: Yes, that's moving in the right direction. Note that if $(V_1,E_1) \subseteq (V_2, E_2)$ then $E_1$ is completely determined by $(V_2,E_2)$ and $(V_1)$. So, suppose it's not wellfounded. Then there is an infinite strictly decreasing sequence $(V_1, E_1) \sqsupseteq (V_2,E_2) \sqsupseteq (V_3,E_3) \sqsupseteq \ldots$. Show that this yields $V_1 \supsetneq V_2 \supsetneq V_2 \supsetneq \ldots$. This is a contradiction, since $V_1$ is finite.

Comment: amazing! thanks Stefan :)

Comment: Sorry, it's suppose to be $\sqsubseteq$.

Comment: That argument made so much sense - you just gave me that little happy feeling when you learn something new.... but wait a second, something doesn't seem right, $(V_1,E_1) \subseteq (V_2, E_2)$ then how can it be smaller? If we swap the order of that first statement, it works right?

Comment: I think it should be :Note that if $(V_2,E_2) \subseteq (V_1,E_1)$ then $E_2 $ is completely determined by $(V_1,E_1)$ and $V_2$, then the rest of the argument makes sense.

Comment: Can we say that since $T_1 \sqsupseteq T_2 \sqsupseteq T_3 .... \leftrightarrow  V_1 \supseteq V_2 \supseteq V_3 $ AND  $E_1 $is the set of all edges in $E_2$ with tail in $V_1$ AND $E_2$ is the set of all edges in $E_3$ with tail in $V_2$ .......... how does this imply that the  vertices are strictly decreasing? It is because the tail is not a part of the same set, we know that the sequence is strictly decreasing???

Comment: Note that $E_3$ is also equal to the set of all edges in $E_1$ whose endpoints (tail) lie in $V_3$. So, if $V_2 = V_3$, then $E_2=E_3$. But this is supposed to be a strictly decreasing sequence, hence $V_2 \supsetneq V_3$.

Comment: Yes, of course.  I was so close though. Thanks :)

Comment: You're very welcome!